# How to retain &quot; and &apos; while parsing xml using bs4 python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to parse an xml file and again write it back to a new xml file.

**Input file:**

```xml
<tag1>
  <tag2 attr1="a1">&quot; example text &quot;</tag2>
  <tag3>
    <tag4 attr2="a2">&quot; example text &quot;</tag4>
    <tag5>
      <tag6 attr3="a3">&apos; example text &apos;</tag6>
    </tag5>
  </tag3>
</tag1>
```

**Script:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("input.xml"), "xml")
f = open("output.xml", "w") 
f.write(soup.encode(formatter='minimal'))
f.close()
```

**Output:**

```xml
<tag1>
  <tag2 attr1="a1"> " example text "  </tag2>
  <tag3>
    <tag4 attr2="a2"> " example text " </tag4>
    <tag5>
      <tag6 attr3="a3"> ' example text ' </tag6>
    </tag5>
  </tag3>
</tag1>
```

I want to retain `&quot;` and `&apos;` . I tried using all the options of encode formatter - Minimal, xml, html, none. But none of them solved this problem.

Then I tried replacing " with `&quot;`  manually.

```
for tag in soup.find_all(text=re.compile("\"")):
    res = tag.string
    res1 = res.replace("\"","&quot;")
    tag.string.replaceWith(res1)
```

But this gave the below output

```xml
<tag1>
  <tag2 attr1="a1"> &amp;quot; example text &amp;quot;  </tag2>
  <tag3>
    <tag4 attr2="a2"> &amp;quot; example text &amp;quot; </tag4>
    <tag5>
      <tag6 attr3="a3"> &apos; example text &apos; </tag6>
    </tag5>
  </tag3>
</tag1>
```

It replaces the & with `&amp;` . I am confused here. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: After replacing it doesn't add any &amp to me. Which version of beautifulsoup are you using?

Comment: I am using bs4 4.3.2

Comment: I am using beautifulsoup 4.2.0 and it works for me.

Comment: Voting to close as this seems to pertain to a very specific build/version.

Comment: Hi @DivakarDass , Now  I am trying to run the same script(adapted) in lxml. Even in lxml the problem, which is mentioned above exists. Do you have any solution for this problem in lxml?

Comment: @radhashankar this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30006369/2087463) also worked for `lxml`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Custom Encode & Output Formatting

You can use a [custom formatter function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) to add these specific entities to the entity substitution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution

def custom_formatter(string):
    """add &quot; and &apos; to entity substitution"""
    return EntitySubstitution.substitute_html(string).replace('"','&quot;').replace("'",'&apos;')

input_file = '''<tag1>
  <tag2 attr1="a1">&quot; example text &quot;</tag2>
  <tag3>
    <tag4 attr2="a2">&quot; example text &quot;</tag4>
    <tag5>
      <tag6 attr3="a3">&apos; example text &apos;</tag6>
    </tag5>
  </tag3>
</tag1>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_file, "xml")

print soup.encode(formatter=custom_formatter)
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag1>
<tag2 attr1="a1">&quot; example text &quot;</tag2>
<tag3>
<tag4 attr2="a2">&quot; example text &quot;</tag4>
<tag5>
<tag6 attr3="a3">&apos; example text &apos;</tag6>
</tag5>
</tag3>
</tag1>
```

The trick is to do it after the `EntitySubstitution.substitute_html()` so your `&`s don't get substituted to `&amp;`s.